# Find the discrepancies in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database.

Suppose that I have a table called "MYTABLE" and it contains the tuples of every dog in the world and the owners:

| NAME | OWNER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Aaron | 81 |
| Aaron | 281 |
| Aaron | 404 |
| Michael | 81 |
| Michael | 281 |
| Michael | 404 |
| Brendan | 281 |
| Brendan | 81 |
| Micon | 404 |
| Micon | 81 |
| Tyson | 404 |

For DEFAULT every DOG must be associated with 3 different owners, in this case the owners are identified by an id: 81, 281 and 404.

How can I know the dogs that are not associated with 3 rows in the table?

I would like this output:

```
Brendan
Micon
Tyson
```

These 3 dogs do not have 3 rows in the given table. They are not associated exactly with owners 81, 281 and 404.

Comment: Nothing tricky at all: simple aggregation with `COUNT()` and post-aggregation filtering with `HAVING` clause.

Comment: It would look something like ==>  `SELECT COUNT(name) as doggie_count, Name
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(OWNER_ID) > 2;`

Answer (score 3):

To find out which `name` is not associated with all three of the 81, 281 and 404 `owner_id`, you can use conditional aggregation in a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN OWNER_ID IN (81, 281, 404) THEN OWNER_ID END) < 3
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME, OWNER_ID) AS
SELECT 'Aaron',    81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aaron',   281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aaron',   404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Michael',  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Michael', 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Michael', 404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brendan', 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brendan',  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brendan', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Different owner_id
SELECT 'Micon',   404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Micon',    81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Micon',    81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Duplicate
SELECT 'Tyson',   404 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Brendan |
> | Micon |
> | Tyson |

---

If you just want the `name` where they do not have three different `owner_id` (any `owner_id`) then:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OWNER_ID) < 3
```

Which, for the same sample data, would output:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Micon |
> | Tyson |

---

If you just want the `name` where there are not three `owner_id` (either unique or not) then:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(OWNER_ID) < 3
```

Which, for the same sample data, outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Tyson |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=46bc2f27124d8ce929c6d6fb1af0de18)*

Answer (score 1):

You can GROUP BY the NAME and the use COUNT(*) to exclude al that have less than 3 owners

> ```
> SELECT "NAME" FROM tab1 GROUP BY "NAME" HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
> ```
>
> ```
> | NAME    |
> | :------ |
> | Brendan |
> | Micon   |
> | Tyson   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e39afd6ca4d57d14c00bde9621d2b386)*