# check for same quantity after applying GROUP BY (tricky scenario)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to check whether the output for a specific account number and for the different organizations is the same and show the discrepancies in Oracle

Imagine i have a table called **myTable** and it contains 2 fields:  **accountnumber** and **org_id**

There exist only 3 **org_id**: 81, 281 and 404

[image]

Dataset:

```
|accountnumber|org_id|
|4435354      |81    |
|4435354      |281   |
|4435354      |404   |
|3333333      |81    |
|3333333      |281   |
|4444444      |81    |
|4444444      |81    |
|4444444      |281   |
|4444444      |404   |
```

I want to find all the different accounts that dont have the exact amount for each org_id

For example:

> account 4435354 has 1 row for org_id 81, 1 row for org_281 and 1 row
> for org_id 404, so in this case it is correct
>
> account 3333333 has 1 row for org_id 81, 1 row for org_281 and none
> for 404 so there exist a discrepancy
>
> account 4444444 has 2 rows for org_id 81, 1 row for org_281 and 1 row
> for org_id 404, so there exist a discrepancy

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER| ORG_ID|COUNT(*)
|3333333      |  81   |1
|3333333      |  281  |1
|3333333      |  404  |0
|4444444      |  81   |2
|4444444      |  281  |1
|4444444      |  404  |1
```

How can i achieve something like that in Oracle?

---

EDIT #1

This scenario is a valid one and should not be displayed

```
|9999999      |81    |
|9999999      |81    |
|9999999      |81    |
|9999999      |404   |
|9999999      |404   |
|9999999      |404   |
|9999999      |281   |
|9999999      |281   |
|9999999      |281   |
```

It is correct because every org_id for that accountnumber has 3 in each one and it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated question: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a7682f3586a0056309781c001ba6827a)

```sql
select *
from (
    select 
        v.*
        ,min(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) min_cnt_org
        ,max(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) max_cnt_org
    from (
        select
          accountnumber
          ,org_id
          ,count(org_id)          over(partition by accountnumber) cnt
          ,count(distinct org_id) over(partition by accountnumber) cnt_distinct
          ,count(*)               over(partition by accountnumber,org_id) cnt_org
          ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id)
             over(partition by accountnumber)
               as orgs
          ,listagg(distinct org_id,',')within group(order by org_id) 
             over(partition by accountnumber)
               as orgs_distinct
        from mytable
        ) v
    ) v2
where cnt_distinct<>3
or min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org;
```

Results:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER     ORG_ID        CNT CNT_DISTINCT    CNT_ORG ORGS          ORGS_DISTINCT  MIN_CNT_ORG MAX_CNT_ORG
------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ------------- -------------- ----------- -----------
      3333333         81          2            2          1 81,281        81,281                   1           1
      3333333        281          2            2          1 81,281        81,281                   1           1
      4444444         81          4            3          2 81,81,281,404 81,281,404               1           2
      4444444         81          4            3          2 81,81,281,404 81,281,404               1           2
      4444444        281          4            3          1 81,81,281,404 81,281,404               1           2
      4444444        404          4            3          1 81,81,281,404 81,281,404               1           2
```

Comment: Thank you, pal!. One more: could you please explain to me this final condition: min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org; ?

Comment: in other words, for your first desired output you want "count(*)" to be equal for all ORG_IDs. For example for 4444444, `MAX_CNT_ORG` = 2, `MIN_CNT_ORG`=1, so since they are not equal (`min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org`) we print them

Comment: For `3333333`, `MAX_CNT_ORG`=1, `MIN_CNT_ORG`=0 => `min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org` too

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was awesome, pal :)

Comment: Pal, i tried the code and it says this: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function"

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230602/avoiding-distinct-option-not-allowed-for-this-function-error-oracle-11g

Answer (score 2):

You already asked almost the same question here: [Find the discrepancies in sql (tricky situation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229337/find-the-discrepancies-in-sql-tricky-situation)
(And you still haven't chosen a right answer there)

Just add `count(*)` or `count(distinct org_id)`: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0888363cee7d4634d05e8b0e84149797)

```sql
select
  accountnumber
  ,count(org_id) cnt
  ,count(distinct org_id) cnt_distinct
  ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id) orgs
  ,listagg(distinct org_id,',')within group(order by org_id) orgs_distinct
from mytable
group by accountnumber;
```

Results:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER        CNT CNT_DISTINCT ORGS          ORGS_DISTINCT
------------- ---------- ------------ ------------- --------------
      3333333          2            2 81,281        81,281
      4435354          3            3 81,281,404    81,281,404
      4444444          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
```

And if you really need all rows separately: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e4e69a1eadd91c3df643a278d3ddc6fb)

```
select
  accountnumber
  ,org_id
  ,count(org_id)          over(partition by accountnumber) cnt
  ,count(distinct org_id) over(partition by accountnumber) cnt_distinct
  ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id)
     over(partition by accountnumber)
       as orgs
  ,listagg(distinct org_id,',')within group(order by org_id) 
     over(partition by accountnumber)
       as orgs_distinct
from mytable;
```

Results:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER     ORG_ID        CNT CNT_DISTINCT ORGS          ORGS_DISTINCT
------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ------------- --------------
      3333333         81          2            2 81,281        81,281
      3333333        281          2            2 81,281        81,281
      4435354         81          3            3 81,281,404    81,281,404
      4435354        281          3            3 81,281,404    81,281,404
      4435354        404          3            3 81,281,404    81,281,404
      4444444         81          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
      4444444         81          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
      4444444        281          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
      4444444        404          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
```

[Listagg documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html):

> For a specified measure, LISTAGG orders data within each group specified in the ORDER BY clause and then concatenates the values of the measure column.

**Update**: you can just add a predicate to filter rows you don't want to output:
[DBFiddle 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9adf1ec6283cd379398334d610bfdf42)

```
select *
from (
    select
      accountnumber
      ,org_id
      ,count(org_id)          over(partition by accountnumber) cnt
      ,count(distinct org_id) over(partition by accountnumber) cnt_distinct
      ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id)
         over(partition by accountnumber)
           as orgs
      ,listagg(distinct org_id,',')within group(order by org_id) 
         over(partition by accountnumber)
           as orgs_distinct
    from mytable) v
where cnt<>3;
```

Results:

```
ACCOUNTNUMBER     ORG_ID        CNT CNT_DISTINCT ORGS          ORGS_DISTINCT
------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ------------- --------------
      3333333         81          2            2 81,281        81,281
      3333333        281          2            2 81,281        81,281
      4444444         81          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
      4444444         81          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
      4444444        281          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
      4444444        404          4            3 81,81,281,404 81,281,404
```

Comment: Hey Saya, thank you for replying!
Oh, i am gonna choose one but both answers were good!

Comment: Sayan, could you please explain to me what is LISTAGG and WITHIN doing in this case?

Comment: @new_programmer look at the updated answer: I've added a short description and a link to documentation of listagg:

Comment: But i do not want to show the one that got the same amount for org_id 81 and org_id 281 and org_id 404. If an account has 2 rows for 81 and 2 rows for 281 and 2 rows for 404 it should not be displayed because every org_id for that account number has the same amount. How can i achieve that?

Comment: i want to show the desired output, not everything at all

Comment: @new_programmer check the update - I've added the filter you want...

Comment: Hey pal, what is this condition for: "cnt<>3"

Comment: and you can make the filter stronger - replace `cnt<>3` with `cnt<>3 or cnd_distinct<>3`

Comment: `cnt` is a number of rows for the `ACCOUNTNUMBER`. `cnd_distinct` is a number of distinct `ORG_ID`. So you can use `cnt<>3 or cnd_distinct<>3`  if you want to filter out accounts which have exactly 3 different orgs without duplicates

Comment: But i can have the scenario where an account has 3 org_id = 81 and 3 org_id = 281 and 3 org_id = 404 and it would be okay beceause there are 3 rows for each organization.

Comment: Do you get me? The thing is that an account may have 3 rows or 6 or 5000 for org_id 81 and the same for 281 and 404 and that would be okay because the amount is the same for that account for org_id 81, 281 and 404

Comment: Take a look, i have updated my question

Comment: @new_programmer please read carefully my comment about `cnt<>3 or cnd_distinct<>3` and try to understand it: `cnt<>3 or cnd_distinct<>3` will show you those rows that have 3 rows with 81, because cnt_distinct = 1 for them

Comment: Just play with filters. for the updated question you need just one: `cnt_distinct<>3`  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=42df988f1d16084410f24a28e338644d

Comment: but check your previous "DESIRED OUTPUT" in the question - you showed 4444444 though it has all 3 different ORG_IDs

Comment: I got to display all the accounts that dont have the same amount of org_id between them. For example 4444444 had 2 rows for org_id 81 but only 1 for the rest that why i wanted to display it

Comment: ah, I see... you could explain it better in your question...

Comment: So I'll add another answer...

Comment: Yeah, that right. That would be the answer i am looking for. Could you please explain to me what is "min_cnt != max_cnt" doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
WITH expected_orgs (org_id) AS (
  SELECT  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 404 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT accountnumber,
       org_id,
       cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT t.accountnumber,
         e.org_id,
         COUNT(t.org_id) AS cnt,
         MIN(COUNT(t.org_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY t.accountnumber) AS min_cnt,
         MAX(COUNT(t.org_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY t.accountnumber) AS max_cnt
  FROM   expected_orgs e
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
         PARTITION BY (t.accountnumber)
         ON (e.org_id = t.org_id)
  GROUP BY
         t.accountnumber,
         e.org_id
)
WHERE  min_cnt != max_cnt;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (accountnumber, org_id) AS
SELECT 4435354,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4435354, 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4435354, 404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3333333,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3333333, 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4444444,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4444444,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4444444, 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4444444, 404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999,  81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999, 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999, 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999, 281 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999, 404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999, 404 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9999999, 404 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCOUNTNUMBER | ORG_ID | CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3333333 | 81 | 1 |
> | 3333333 | 281 | 1 |
> | 3333333 | 404 | 0 |
> | 4444444 | 81 | 2 |
> | 4444444 | 281 | 1 |
> | 4444444 | 404 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dc3fb4a8320250a39dac3af7592cd79e)*

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!. I'm checking it out :)

Comment: No, there is a mistake in here pal. I have updated my question

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=00fbfbbb7f9363735c6d045f277bdbf5
take a look. The output should be the same, but it is adding the new data i put and it is wrong

Comment: @new_programmer do you want `min_cnt != max_cnt`? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9946d64164963ad1bc328da8641696c7

Comment: @new_programmer Updated for your clarified question.