# Avoiding DISTINCT option not allowed for this function error (Oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I am getting this error message while running some SQL in Oracle DATABASE (Oracle 11g R2)

[image]

Code:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        v.*
        ,min(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) min_cnt_org
        ,max(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) max_cnt_org
    from (
        select
          accountnumber
          ,org_id
          ,count(org_id)          over(partition by accountnumber) cnt
          ,count(distinct org_id) over(partition by accountnumber) cnt_distinct
          ,count(*)               over(partition by accountnumber,org_id) cnt_org
          ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id)
             over(partition by accountnumber)
               as orgs
          ,listagg(distinct org_id,',')within group(order by org_id) 
             over(partition by accountnumber)
               as orgs_distinct
        from mytable
        ) v
    ) v2
where cnt_distinct<>3
or min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org;
```

SQL FIDDLE shows the same error:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=111c3566da71bc6205502bbdf9d3a992

[image]

How can i make it work?

Comment: Switch to Oracle 21 c and it will work fine. `Distinct` for `list_agg` is a new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `listagg(distinct...` : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd47b06a2d6218529cb6a6d0fa6bd678

```
select *
from (
    select 
        v.*
        ,min(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) min_cnt_org
        ,max(cnt_org)over(partition by accountnumber) max_cnt_org
    from (
        select
          accountnumber
          ,org_id
          ,count(org_id)          over(partition by accountnumber) cnt
          ,count(distinct org_id) over(partition by accountnumber) cnt_distinct
          ,count(*)               over(partition by accountnumber,org_id) cnt_org
          ,listagg(org_id,',')within group(order by org_id)
             over(partition by accountnumber)
               as orgs
        from mytable
        ) v
    ) v2
where cnt_distinct<>3
or min_cnt_org!=max_cnt_org;
```

Comment: Thanks, pal!. Can you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231044/the-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long-listagg

Comment: It says: "result of string concatenation is too long"